# Nikto commandline options

Tags: penetration-test, vulnerability-scanners

I was reading from Nikto's site on the commandline options used and I am curious about this option

https://cirt.net/nikto2-docs/options.html

```
-ask
Whether to ask about submitting updates: yes (ask about each-- the default), no (don't ask, just send), auto (don't ask, just send).
```

May I know what is it sending and to where? If I don't use this option, what is the default behaviour of Nikto?

I am asking this from a Pentest point of view where we do not want to accidentally send sensitive customer data to third parties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option looks for version strings Nikto doesn't know about and sends them to `cirt.net`:

> If the outdated Nikto plugin sees a web server it doesn't know of, or a version that is later than that defined in `db_outdated`, then it will send this information back to `cirt.net` for inclusion in future versions of Nikto. Server specific information (e.g. IP addresses or hostnames) are not sent.

[*Nikto manual*](https://cirt.net/nikto2-docs/configuration.html)

While it says Nikto doesn't send specific information like hostnames to `cirt.net`, there is always the possibility of a mistake such as custom version strings which disclose information being sent. This feature can be disabled in the [configuration file](https://github.com/sullo/nikto/blob/6d1c07d13c8fa428b6860cd7d1d8dd2a5395e6aa/program/nikto.conf.default).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.

What if this option was not specified on the commandline? Will it send the details silently?

Comment: If you use the default configuration file, it will ask for each individual item